# Как правильно сделать preg_replace?

Tags: php

Есть например вот такой код:

```
zz<img class=\"cont_img\" src=\"1/5451.jpg\" alt=\"\'Car\" title=\"\'Car\" />qq<img class=\"cont_img\" src=\"1/1323123123.jpg\" alt=\"\'Car\" title=\"\'Car\" />qweqwe<img class=\"sadasd\" src=\"1/5451.jpg\" alt=\"\'Car\" title=\"\'Car\" />
```

Как мне вырезать из него все теги `<img>`  в которых есть  **1/5451.jpg**  ?
То есть в итоге должно получиться:

```
zz qq<img class=\"cont_img\" src=\"1/1323123123.jpg\" alt=\"\'Car\" title=\"\'Car\" />qweqwe
```

Comment: Вы не должны разбирать HTML регулярками. Потому что регулярки не предназначены для разбора HTML. Регулярки — это не то средство, которое может корректно распарсить HTML. Регулярки недостаточно серьёзное средство, чтобы поонять конструкции, которые могут встретиться в HTML. Даже @ReinRaus не всегда может распарсить HTML регулярками. Каждый раз, когда вы пытаетесь разобрать HTML регулярками, китайские хакеры сливают ваши базы и подбрасывают вам вирус[.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/276994)

Comment: @igumnov: локализованная версия :)

Comment: @VladD Ребята не стоит парсить HTML регулярными выражениями. Вы молодые, шутливые, вам все легко. Это не то. Это не иерархия Хомского и даже не регулярная грамматика. Сюда лучше не лезть. Серьезно, любой из вас будет жалеть. Лучше закройте тему и забудьте что тут писалось. Я вполне понимаю что данным сообщением вызову дополнительный интерес, но хочу сразу предостеречь пытливых - стоп. Остальные просто не найдут.

Comment: @igumnov: Не надо шутить с HTML, б****. Здесь другая грамматика. Это не емэйл, это не поиск слов в тексте. Джордж, твои регулярки здесь порвут на части. Это 250 тысяч отборных зловредных юзеров б****! Они всё разнесут! Они найдут дыру в твоей грамматике за час! Они заинжектят в весь твой SQL, сграбят все твои пароли, посадят свою рекламу на все твои страницы. И ты повторишь ту же ошибку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зовите экзорциста @VladD!

HTML действительно лучше в парсере разбирать, это не дело регулярных выражений.
Возьми любой парсер, например, [этот](http://habrahabr.ru/post/176635/) и поищи через него что нужно.
Например для парсера в по ссылке это как-то так:

```
<?
$dom = new simple_html_dom();
$html = load("zz<img class=\"cont_img\" src=\"1/5451.jpg\" alt=\"\'Car\" title=\"\'Car\" />qq<img class=\"cont_img\" src=\"1/1323123123.jpg\" alt=\"\'Car\" title=\"\'Car\" />qweqwe<img class=\"sadasd\" src=\"1/5451.jpg\" alt=\"\'Car\" title=\"\'Car\" />");

foreach($html->find('img') as $img)
  if($img->src && stristr('1/5451.jpg', $img->src)) // Если, конечно, эта строка в атрибуте src
    $img->outertext = '';

print $html->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходим следующий `preg_replace`:

```
$string = preg_replace('@<img([^/>]+)1/5451.jpg(.+?)/>@', '', $string);
```